How to copy all the containers of a source storage account to destination storage account, as a folders in the container?
Scenario: I have plenty of blob containers in a source storage account.
They should be copied to destination storage account but in a different manner i.e,
Description:
All the Source Containers should be copied as a folders to the destination storage container.

Note: I have the partial solution of listing the source storage account containers but I do not have any idea in ADF on how to make work the above scenario.
Manual Process how we are doing:

From the Azure Storage explorer, we will download the blob container one by one.
Copy that blob containers data to the folders created with source blob container names in the destination storage account container.


By following the same procedure as this SO answer, you can achieve your requirement. But here, as you want to copy the containers as folders in the target storage account, you need to parameterize the folder name in the target dataset instead of target container.
You can check the below step by step process. This will create the target folder and copies all the contents of the source containers into that.
To get the list of containers of the source storage account, create binary dataset without any path. Don't give any container or folder or any file name. Use this dataset for the Get meta data activity with a ChildItems field. This will give all the container names like below.
"childItems": [
        {
            "name": "zipoutput2",
            "type": "Folder"
        },
        {
            "name": "zipsinput",
            "type": "Folder"
        },
        {
            "name": "zipsoutput",
            "type": "Folder"
        }
    ]

Give this array to a For-each activity. Inside For-Each, you need to use two copy activities one for the copy of the folders in the source container and another is for the copy of the files in the source container.
Create Source and sink datasets like below.
Source dataset:
Use the dataset parameter for the container name.

Sink dataset:
Here, give your target container name and use the dataset parameter for the folder name.

Copy activity1 for folders copy:
Give the source container name @item().name from the for-each to the dataset parameter and follow the below configurations in the source.

Give below configurations in the sink.

Copy activity2 for the files copy:
Use the same source and sink datasets for this activity as well. Follow the below configurations.


Now, debug the pipeline and it will give the expected results.

NOTE: If the source containers are empty, then folders for those will not be created in the target as empty folders are not supported in Blob storage.
